# Return result of value co-occurrences query as a map

Tags: node.js, marklogic

How to specify the **map** option in withOptions in the following query?

```
dbRead.values.read(
  vb.fromIndexes(
    vb.range(vb.property(uriElementName), vb.datatype('string')),
    vb.range(vb.property(versionElementName), vb.datatype('unsignedLong'))
  )
  .where(query)
  .withOptions({values: ['descending']})
)
```

I want to get the result of above query as a map (JSON Object) where uriElementName values are keys and versionElementName values are corresponding values.

I have checked MarkLogic Node.js Client API documentation but could not find any example.

Answer (score 0):

[Refining the Results of a Values or Co-Occurrence Query](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_71023)

> - Use valuesBuilder.BuiltQuery.withOptions to specify values query options or constrain results to particular forests. For a list of options, see the API documentation for [cts.values](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.values) (JavaScript) or [cts:values](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values) (XQuery).

One of the options listed is `map`:

> "map"
> Return results as a JavaScript Object instead of as a Sequence.

So, I believe you should be able to use:

```
.withOptions({values: ['descending', 'map']})
```